# Creating A Folder In Visual Studio 2015 Adds It As A Sub-Folder Of An Existing Folder

Tags: c#, visualstudio

New folder is not displayed as a separate folder. Instead, it is created as a sub folder of an existing one

[image]

Please, has anyone encountered this problem ? In M/S Visual Studio, a new folder is created as a sub-folder to an existing one. This is not the way it should work.

To create a new folder (as a separate folder on the tree), I right click the main C# icon (in this case, `CV_Lib_Test`) and select add >> Folder.

But the folder is created as a sub-folder under the "Menu" folder.

I have also done a google search [from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294731.aspx)

I am aware that i can Rename a copied folder - as work around.

But, I just wanted to know if anyone has been able to solve this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NewFolder1** folder is not created as sub-folder of **menu** folder, Visual Studio just alphabetically sorts it. If VS would create **NewFolder1** as sub-folder of menu, you wont' be able to see it unless **menu** folder is expanded (in your screenshot it is collapsed). Hopefully this clears out the picture.